# Setting starting DOM in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, dom, tinymce

When I run `init()` and create an tinymce instance, I want to have some wrapping `div`s for styling purposes.

For example, imagine this is the initial DOM inside TinyMCE's iframe when the page starts up:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="myWrapper">
    <div class="myWrapperContainer">

--> User input area <--

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then when I get the user input content:

```
var userContent = tinymce.get("myTextarea").getContent();
```

I don't want the wrapper `div`s to be included in `userContent`. I just want the HTML inside the wrapper `div`s

How should I go about this?

Comment: What version of TinyMCE?  For example, I am using 4.1.9 and it doesn't create an iframe - so I would just put a textarea where your `User input area` is and style the outer myWrapper containers.

Comment: It should be the latest version - version 6 I assume.